# Custom e-commerce display for specific users

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, menus

I am starting to build a WordPress website, with one specific functionality I’m struggling with.

The business sells custom, recurring products to industrial customers. So, the desire is each customer can only view and purchase the items relevant to them (I.e, Product A only displayed for Company 1, Product B only for Company 2, etc).

Is Profile Builder, Client Portal, and WooCommerce the correct and best “plugin stack” for this application?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the Profile Builder, Client Portal, and WooCommerce plugins can help you implement the desired functionality.

Profile Builder allows you to create custom user registration forms and front-end user profile forms. This can be used to create a custom registration form for your industrial customers, where they can select their company and the products they are interested in.

Client Portal allows you to create a private area on your website where your customers can access their own content. This can be used to create a private area where each customer can only see the products relevant to them.

And of course WooCommerce will allow you to sell products and services on your website. This can be used to create the custom, recurring products that your industrial customers can purchase.

Together, these three plugins can help you implement the desired functionality for your WordPress website.

However, you *may* need to customize the plugins or write custom code to fully implement the desired functionality.